# virtualbox host win 7 gues solaris 10, can't connect to gues

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, solaris-10

I disabled firewall, created a network bridge on the host(MAC Bridge Miniport) 169.254.193.127
host Win-7 169.254.162.162, gues Sol-10 169.254.163.163, mask 255.255.0.0, OS's are 64 bits.
In VBox network is set to Bridged.
I google many many articles, no aswers. After this connection is made I whant to install Oracle 11g on Solaris gues. This will require file sharing.
Badly need help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Host only adapter mode. It's the simplest one for network sharing.
Make both computers to same workgroup.

Note : For bridged mode you need a router.

Refer this [article](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-network-sharing.html) for any help.

Comment: Did you try to ping ?

Comment: Thank you, I have made the change to Host-Only -- no cable connected. now I can ping the gues but the gues can't ping the host. I am using VBox 4.1.16 r78094. I created the share acording to the "article".  I see on Solaris gues network is Disconnected, I dont quite know how to resolve.

Comment: Are you able to ping between guests?
Are you able to ping from host to guest and guest to host?

Comment: I only have one guest and it can't ping the host, but the host can ping the guest.

Comment: I got it to work but with VMWare Player. Win-7 as rigourus firewall settings, I disabled them (they come back after reboot) and I used this document http://rednectar.net/2011/07/20/vmware-interfaces-tutorial/ - and made a host only guest. BTW a goo document. Thank you verry mutch for the reply.  HOO YEA - the guest still cant ping the host but i works - I also had to configure a DSA key for the user to ssh to the box